# How can I blur the background in Skype?

Tags: video, skype, webcam

How can I blur the background in Skype?

I read on https://www.ultimatepocket.com/skypes-cool-useful-background-blurring-feature-goes-live-for-the-pc-and-mac ([mirror](http://archive.is/JTUmZ)):

> [blurring the background is] available is what Microsoft calls Skype (Version 8) on Windows, Mac, and Linux, or what you might know as the traditional Skype app.
>
> [image]

But I don't see the option on my side despite updating Skype:

[image]

I use Skype version 8.41.0.54 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Windows 10 RS5.

After updating to Skype version 8.46.0.60, I saw:

[image]

[image]

But still no "blur the background" option.

Comment: I don't have anyone I can call right now to test it, but try this - begin a video call then hover over the video button. ‘Blur my background’ will then appear as an option, and you can toggle it on.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, didn't work

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Are you using the Desktop or UWP application?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Why don't I see the option to blur my video?**

In order to blur your background in Skype, your computer processor needs to support Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (AVX2). For more information, check with your computer manufacturer."

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34896/what-is-background-blur-in-skype ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190717173841/https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34896/what-is-background-blur-in-skype))

Answer (score 0):

The blur the background option finally showed up on Skype version 8.46.0.60:

[image]

Comment: Any more info how this showed up? It would be really helpful for others..

Comment: @ShahAbazKhan sorry, I have no idea!